# Is "flowery language" frowned upon in engineering and STEM related research?

Tags: publications, writing, writing-style, collaboration, academic-life

I work in an engineering field (related to AI, machine learning, etc.) and something I found interesting is whenever I use "big words" or even long words  like "substantiate" or "corroborates" while compiling a draft to be submit to a conference and such, I will get a request from my co-authors demanding me to change them.

For example:

- "these related works are germane to our present discussion." I got a
  request to change the word "germane" to something else. Really?
- Or "...therefore, the scenario considered in [reference] is situated diametrically
  opposite to ours." I was told to change "diametrically". Really?
- "The experiments in [references] corroborates with our results". I was told to change corroborates to "collaborates".

There are a lot more examples, especially in the latest draft. But I don't want to point them out just in case my colleagues are reading this forum. :-)

Mind you, this is all in the introduction of the paper, hence no way to confuse it with any technical terminology. This happens to me so frequently that I became almost clairvoyant as to which sentences I will need to rephrase in the upcoming revision.

My intention is merely for the writing to be conversational, and this is done in order to distinguish our works from some of the truly monotonous writing styles pervasive in this field.

Also worth noting is that some of the top authors in this field uses very flowery language (sometimes in my opinion excessively so), so you can say that I'm perhaps subconsciously trying to imitate them.

We are working in a North American university. However, some of my colleagues are non-native speakers (who have stayed here for something like 20 plus years). I wonder if this phenomenon is more wide spread or it is just happening to me.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion, answers, linguistic theories, or dissection of the grammatical accuracy of the example sentences; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112717/discussion-on-question-by-roy-ayers-is-flowery-language-frowned-upon-in-engine). Please read [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4230/why-do-the-moderators-move-comments-to-chat-and-how-should-i-behave-afterwards/4231) before posting another comment.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm adding an answer for the purpose of voting, because I completely disagree with the (currently 8) answers and highly-upvoted comments to this question. None of the examples that the OP gave are uncommon or exotic words, to a well-read and reasonably-literate English speaker. To me, they were all entirely transparent. If you put them in a list of random words and asked me which ones were "flowery" I'd be hard-pressed to identify them. The idea that professional academics need to look these words up and claim that they are new to them is really quite hard to believe.

I'm reminded of a time I got refused a programming job for suggesting a [standard textbook algorithm](http://www.madmath.com/2015/12/that-time-i-didnt-get-job.html) ([Horner's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method)), which the reviewer couldn't understand; similarly, when I sometimes bring this up online, many commenters likewise agree they would prohibit it from any codebase as "too opaque". But how can (computer) science progress without using new observations/algorithms?

Likewise, I've overheard my colleagues in the English department at the community college where I work (U.S.) saying that they now routinely have science PhDs from nearby graduate schools being referred to them for writing assistance, because those students commonly can't write even a simple English sentence correctly. So I think that there's an aspect of writing skills (and standards) for students in science programs that has very much fallen down in recent years.

The fact that you observe top authors in your field using a similar writing style is the most important piece of evidence, in my opinion. I'd recommend that you continue being literate, write in a style that feels natural and expressive to you, and pursue the goal of developing into a top researcher/author in your field.

Also, I would recommend that you get different co-authors in the top tier of your field. Consider looking for articles that you find inspiring and well-written and reaching out to those authors for actual (ahem) collaborations.

Comment: I would disagree with this, I'm a native english speaker and would say I'm well read but I needed to look up germane (and couldn't determine its meaning from the example sentence). Further, since science is a global endeavour, I would say its unfair to expect non-native speakers to have to develop native level English skills as well as competency in their field of expertise. Rather it makes more sense for native speakers to learn how to use common words more skillfully.

Comment: @N A McMahon As a non-native English speaker, I must say that the idea that non-native English speakers would find same difficult to comprehend as the native English speakers do looks like a very good example of bias. In fact I know quite a number of people who have the opposite issue: As non-native speakers, they don't use the "common" words, and are more comfortable with "flowery" language instead, because they tend to be more common in the subsets of English language they use in their daily interactions with the language.

Comment: @AndrejaKo that may be true, though what do you mean by flowery language? For example I'd expect a non-native speaker who works in machine learning to know "algorithm" and "neural network" though  I wouldn't call them flowery since these are the simplest words that convey the broad meaning of what they want to get across. Though I wouldn't expect other non-native speakers to know these words. However I might count "neural network" as flowery if you use it to refer to a person who you trained to do something.

Comment: I'm also probably considering worst case researcher's English skills rather than the skills of the average researcher who is a non-native English speaker.

Comment: *The idea that professional academics need to look these words up and claim that they are new to them is really quite hard to believe.* I looked up "germane" too. Thanks to the OP for adding it to my vocabulary! :-) I probably fall under the category of "professional academics" though, of course, I'm not a native English speaker..

Comment: My opinion is that even if these words can be recognised by the reader, they can still stand out as being unnecessary or inappropriate, and thus make the reading experience far less fluent and much more unnatural. I'm sure that such language would be common in e.g. fiction books, but in scientific writing where the overwhelming norm is to use simple and easy words even beginners learning English can understand, such "flowery" language would stand out and not in a good way. (Personally, I did understand the words in the examples given by OP, but found their appearance disruptive to reading.)

Comment: I'm not a native speaker but I prefer "nice" sentences over Wiki-style "Simple English" (which @yarchik mentions in his comment to another answer). Academic writing is not meant to be a technical documentation. IMHO it is acceptable, and even desired, to show off some level of erudition. Sometimes this can be overdone, and then it's bad. Otherwise it's ok.

Comment: Re Horner's method, that's absolutely hilarious. I didn't know that alg by name until just now, but not only is it in the textbook you mentioned, but it's also in the bible of C itself, K&R (at least 2nd edition), which is where I first encountered it. For a fellow C programmer (your interviewer) to not be familiar with it is frankly astounding. Re "germane", I'm a native English speaker with a substantial interest in linguistics, but had never heard the word before today.

Comment: While I sympathize with your view, I'm not entirely sure if your complaint here is germane (at least everyone here now knows what this means!) to the misconception at the core of this particular question. Good writing is quite important, but applying an impeccable lexicon would, I believe, come second to the more important maxim of not using any words when fewer would do. This is the main point of the other answers and I agree that this should be the queriers primary concern with the phrases displayed here. I do agree that dumbing down one's vocabulary should be resisted, but not at all costs.

Comment: Now that I've satisfied my inner HP Lovecraft, let me add that I also do not like the certain amount of contempt that some people direct at others for not knowing _just one_ thing, word, book, algorithm, person, movie, have it you. I mean, most of those things are highly cultural, but guess what, cultures differ around the world. Now, it seems here that I'm doing exactly the same thing here, so let me add that I don't exactly direct this to you in particular, it is just this particular viewpoint I dislike. I would not, for example, tell others not to work with you based on this viewpoint.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree, but need to point out that using an advanced english vocabulary needs to be done *perfectly*, i.e. not by merely filling in redundant, fancy near-synonyms. Only *then* the reader actually profits, and in more than one way!

Comment: @Discretelizard, such contempt may be contemptuous, but the typical response (even if implied) along the lines 'I don't know this thing, so it's not needed/so shouldn't you/so you accomodate my mediocrity' is much worse. Not all of them are like that, of course, but many are, and the examples with refusing the job/contributions of the algorithm from the answer are of this sort.

Comment: As a non-native speaker I like learning new (more specific, flowery) words. I looked up all of the examples. But when reading a paper, it should be the content that is nontrivial / challenging for me, not the phrasing. Technical works should imho be simple and precise. Parts like the introduction are candidates for more complex words though.

Comment: Why haven't you consulted any data in making of this answer? Ngram shows "germane" to be several orders of magnitude rarer than "relevant".

Answer (score 168):

There's nothing wrong with long words. The real issue with your writing is that it is redundant.

> "these related works are germane to our present discussion."

In this sentence, "germane" just stands for "related", so you're effectively saying "these related works are related". Here you are using the English cliche of pairing a common word with a rare synonym, which we also see in phrases like "trials and tribulations" or "vim and vigor". As in these examples, you include the common word because without it, people won't always know what the rare word means. But the very act of doing that makes the rare word completely useless. Redundancy in this form should basically always be removed.

> "...therefore, the scenario considered in [reference] is situated diametrically opposite to ours."

This is another example of the cliche above. The word "diametrically" isn't doing any work the word "opposite" isn't already doing. It's only there for the purpose of being a long word.

> "The experiments in [references] corroborates with our results".

This is not correct usage: the word "with" shouldn't be there. Incorrect usage of a long word is very bad: people who don't know it will be annoyed with you, and people who do will judge you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112787/discussion-on-answer-by-knzhou-is-flowery-language-frowned-upon-in-engineering).

Comment: For the third point, I believe the OP was getting an incorrect replacement, as well.  I don't think "collaborates" fits the sentence at all.

Comment: +1 for the phrases "trials and tribulations" and "vim and vigor", which are actually examples of [hendiadys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hendiadys), from a Greek term that means "one by means of two". Some more examples of hendiadys: "part and parcel", "nice and warm", "the steep and thorny way" (from *Hamlet*). Unless one's rhetorical skills are exceptionally well developed, it may be wise not to overuse hendiadys -- especially in engineering and STEM fields...

Comment: "Diametrically opposite" has an actual purpose: it's more intense and precise than simply "opposite". I've heard the phrase many times. It even has a dictionary entry: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diametrically%20opposite

Answer (score 64):

The rule is:

> Never use an uncommon word where a common word can do the job just as well.

This is to make it easier to read your work.

You said

> My intention is merely for the writing to be conversational

However, "Germane," "Scenario," and "Diametrically" are not words used in conversation.   Words like these will immediately jump out to native English speakers as inappropriate for scientific language.  In my personal experience, highly educated native Chinese speakers know these uncommon words and use them in their writing, but some native English speakers will not know them and quite a lot of other English language learners, who are the majority of your readership, will not know them.

Write as simply as possible, but no simpler.

Comment: I would disagree. Maybe my case is rare but in academia at least "germane" and "Diametrically" come up more frequently than in casual conversation.  "Scenario" is used quite often in business. I agree write simpler because it conveys understanding - but "germane", "diametrically" (though I hear "orthogonal" more), and "scenario" are not complicated words and, speaking as a native speaker, are well known in spoken (American) English. I'd almost argue "germane" is too casual for this paper and "related" is significantly more proper in this context.

Comment: Yes, as a native speaker it wouldn't even register with me that there was anything unusual in those words. Of course, there will be some native speakers who don't know them, but they wouldn't be considered difficult words by the sort of people who read academic papers.

Comment: @CL40 Note that "orthogonal" and "diametrically opposite" are not synonyms. The first is more like "irrelevant" than "opposite". (And you never said otherwise, but your comment could be taken to imply that they are synonyms.)

Comment: Re "Never use an uncommon word...", the given examples ARE common words that should be familiar to any educated English speaker.

Comment: I have never heard of "germane" in either a casual or academic setting prior to this question, and "diametrically" is uncommon in my experience as well. Though I would say "scenario" is common enough in STEM communities.

Comment: "germane" vs "related" (synonym): https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?cat=1289&geo=US&q=germane,related

Comment: @Pat-Laugh better: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_end=2019&content=germane%2Crelated%2Crelevant&smoothing=3&corpus=26&year_start=1700&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgermane%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crelated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crelevant%3B%2Cc0  FWIW I did hear germane before but I did not actually know the meaning. I thought it is something like salient. I am an ESL speaker, hopefully reasonably educated.

Comment: @CL40 "Diametrically opposite" and "orthogonal" have two very different meanings.

Comment: One might say that "orthogonal" and "diametrically opposite" are orthogonal.

Comment: All the debate about the meaning of these words in the comments further emphasizes that they are *not* common words.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist That doesn't follow. It is a more likely conclusion that the site targets an audience of a certain narrow demographic with a specific vocabulary.

Comment: @Frank Yes - the exact demographic that is actually reading and writing STEM papers professionally.

Answer (score 39):

Yeah, I've had this before. My PhD supervisor* removed several of my perfectly fine English words with simpler ones. I still have the svn commit message saying, basically: "removing difficult words, but I'll allow 'aberrant'. I've learned something today :)".

In hindsight, I am not convinced that my supervisor was wrong. While my words were accurate, it doesn't hurt to write papers in a form that is more easily accessible to a wide audience. After all, I would like my papers to be read by an audience that does not exclusively stem from a native English speaking country. There are 1.1 billion Chinese people on this planet, and they encompass a substantial number of scientists.

The "corroborates->collaborates" suggestion is obviously wrong, and you can respectfully point that out to your co-author. But for the other two suggestions, I tend to agree with your co-authors that going for a simpler, shorter version is probably a better idea. For instance, where you write "these related works are germane to our present discussion", what is the point of the sentence anyway? Obviously, any related work that you discuss is assumed to be relevant to the discussion in the paper that you currently write, because everyone assumes that you're not wasting everyone's time. And where you write: "...therefore, the scenario considered in [reference] is situated diametrically opposite to ours.", you can also write "hence, the scenario from [x] is the polar opposite of ours". I don't think that the one version is necessarily better than the other, but I do think that they hold the same information, and if one version makes your co-authors happier than the other, then why not go for that version?

*my PhD and subsequent research is in the field of data mining, so definitely STEM.

Comment: Well, a good reason might be that in academic journals, *diametrically opposite* is  far more common than *polar opposite*, and most readers are more familiar with the normal academic register. [Even in normal printed books, *polar opposite* only became more common since around 2010](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_end=2019&year_start=1800&content=diametrically+opposite%2C+polar+opposite&smoothing=3&corpus=26&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdiametrically%20opposite%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpolar%20opposite%3B%2Cc0). Using ones normal academic language generally makes things *easier* to understand.

Comment: And trying to 'simplify' ones language normally makes things more difficult for international readers, because they are used to the normal academic register, not what people think is 'easier' to understand. (Full disclosure: I teach academic reading and writing skills for non-native English speaking students at UK universities).

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. - what are you talking about? Replacing "germane" with "relevant" will improve readability for learners by a hundred fold.

Comment: @Davor I seriously doubt it, but the argument is that scientific papers are written in Academese (instead of English), a language where "germane" is more easily understood than "relevant". Researchers learn Academese, not English, by reading papers and going to conferences, and should be addressed in that language, the reasoning goes. I would really much like to see an empirical study of that (= give researchers that are non-native speakers a text in simple English vs. Academese and test how fast they read, how much they remember etc. ; test PhD students vs older researchers too).

Answer (score 29):

> We are working in a North American university. However, some of my colleagues are non-native speakers (who have stayed here for something like 20 plus years). I wonder if this phenomenon is more wide spread or it is just happening to me.

No, I would ask you the same thing.
When you write a paper, you want to write it for an international audience to maximize the number of people who can read it.
For me that means two things:

- When possible write it in English rather than in your native language, since English is the lingua franca for a lot of STEM fields
- Don't make it unnecessarily hard to read for a non-native speaker.

I am not a native speaker, but after working 8 years in international companies I think I am fairly proficient in English. And I would have to look up the words "germane" and "corroborates".
It is fine to use less common terms if they are needed for precision or are common in industry. If I need to look up a word and find that it could have been expressed in a simpler way, I am getting frustrated. I would probably even think less of the paper, since a good writer would be able to convey complex technical situations in a simpler way and someone who uses flowery language might want to hide a lack of substance.
If I am going through a lot of papers, I just might skip one that is unnecessarily frustrating.

Comment: One of the Wikipedia languages is "Simple English". Are you suggesting it should be exclusively used in scientific literature?

Comment: @yarchik the key point in this answer (+1), to me, is that less common terms should be used _when they are needed for their specific meaning_. For example, nobody would be an eye at the phrase "results were inconclusive" in scientific writing - while it is uncommon in spoken language, it is a precise an succinct replacement for a longer phrase, something like "no clear conclusions could be drawn from these results". OP's example "these related works are germane to the our present discussion" can be restated in a simpler way, and possibly removed altogether, without any loss.

Comment: @yarchik See for example Randall Munroe's *The Thing Explainer* (the book uses only the ten-hundred most common words)

Comment: @yarchik English as the lingua franca is quite different from "Simple English". Its users are usually proficient in the language, but they may have a narrow vocabulary, as they only use the language in specific contexts. They may have huge gaps in the vocabulary native speakers learn as kids or in school, and they may have a hard time understanding idioms that require a specific cultural context or where words are used outside their literal meanings.

Comment: @Jouni, true. There were times when I knew "increase velocity" but didn't know "speed up" :) However, we learn by reading _good_ language (even in scientific papers) rather than the 'dumbed down' one.

Comment: @Zeus - yes, but the point of scientific papers is not to teach English vocabulary. Read some Tolkien for that.

Comment: @Davor I am not sure, are you saying that reading Tolkien will improve your manuscript writing skills?

Comment: @yarchik - no, I am not.

Answer (score 18):

In a famous literary feud, William Faulkner allegedly said of Ernst Hemingway's writing that it has

> never been known to send the reader to the dictionary

Hemingway's response pretty much sums it up:

> Poor Faulkner. Does he really think big emotions come from big words? He thinks I don’t know the ten-dollar words. I know them all right. But there are older and simpler and better words, and those are the ones I use.

If you have to pick one side, err on Hemingway's in academic writing. The *only* point of an academic paper is to get your ideas across to your readers in the most efficient way possible. In particular, it is *not* to impress them with your English prowess.

Answer (score 14):

It is not necessary to keep a language in your papers sound like manuals, but at least it should not be confusing and overwhelmingly long. The language should be balanced between boring and flowery. Especially for people who read your paper to learn something new it is important that things are clear and precise. Stick to words you define, do not use synonymous words you did not define for things you defined (which is also part of a flowery language, but this can be really confusing).

So, it remains to cite [Karl Popper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Popper):

> Jeder Intellektuelle hat eine ganz besondere Verantwortung. Er hatte das Privileg und die Gelegenheit, zu studieren; dafür schuldet er es seinen Mitmenschen (oder „der Gesellschaft“), die Ergebnisse seiner Studien in der einfachsten und klarsten und verständlichsten Form darzustellen. Das Schlimmste – die Sünde gegen den heiligen Geist – ist, wenn die Intellektuellen versuchen, sich ihren Mitmenschen gegenüber als große Propheten aufzuspielen und sie mit orakelnden Philosophien zu beeindrucken. Wer’s nicht einfach und klar sagen kann, der soll schweigen und weiterarbeiten, bis er’s klar sagen kann.

Translation by me:

> All intellectual people have a particular responsibility. They had the privilege and the opportunity to study; in this way, they owe their fellows (or the society) to show the results of their studies in the clearest and most comprehensible form. The worst [...] thing [they] can do to their fellows is to play prophet and to impress them with oracle-like philosophies. Someone who cannot say it clearly, should be quiet and continue working until they can say it clearly.

Comment: It depends on your audience.  I would say that you'd never go wrong using the language of your peers if that is the target audience.  The only odd factor in this situation is that the co-authors are less likely to have the same reading grade-level as their English-native speaking counterparts.  Note, in the case of dumb Americans or highly motivated foreign nationals, the opposite can be true.

Comment: @Astara: The OP mentioned that _some_ (but not necessarily all) of their colleagues are non-native speakers.

Comment: I addressed your point in a short answer posted as a comment to the OP.  Unfortunately it was deleted.  It cannot be posted as an ANSWER because I don't have enough points to post an answer -- only to post a  comment.  Obviously the rules are more important than any answer.  In such an environment what can one do, but attempt to do the right thing.

Answer (score 13):

The main objective of scientific writing is (or, at least, is supposed to be) to communicate the results, proofs, and general thought process in the clearest way possible. By itself, using a rare or not very well-known word is not a crime and it may make sense, for example, when it has precisely the meaning you intend to convey while more common words can only approximate it or have alternative meanings that you want to exclude, so if you do it sparingly and with clear understanding of the logic behind your preference, I would say "go ahead!".

That some people may have to look at the dictionary one extra time doesn't bother me too much: I like to learn new words myself and the common practice of sending the reader to the library to dig up some hard to get journal for a proof of some half-page long lemma that could be easily included into the main text irritates me much more. The bad practice, IMHO, is only using fancy words merely for the sake of doing it.

Comment: Words which have such a precise and special meaning that most people don't know them probably loose this precision when translated - and even if not, if they are too special to be known to the majority of native speakers - since exacly this very special nature might be particularly hard to translate.

Comment: @user151413 I guess you've missed the point. People won't look up the word in e.g. English-Chinese dictionary, but in an English-English one, so no translation is implied.

Comment: @ciamej Native chinese speakers will look up the word in an english-chinese dictionary.  You should keep in mind that most of the time you write for an *international* audience. And international people, even with a good command of english, have a far more restricted vocabulary when it comes to special words than an educated native speaker.  Those are the people who get difficulties reading such papers first.

Comment: @user151413 In my opinion if you work in a given language, you should be proficient in that language. If your language skills are at the basic level you simply should improve or resign. That might be unjust for non-native speakers of English, but I believe the same would apply if the current lingua franca of science was French, German, Spanish, Japanese, Greek or even Latin. We cannot lower standards to the lowest possible to accommodate as many people as possible, because we will end up with Wikipedia's Simple English. This does not improve communication. Improving one's language skills does.

Comment: @ciamej I don't think this is a healty attitude.  And we are not talking about "simple english" - we are taking about restricting to a reasonable vocabulary of english, without demanding from people with a different cultural background to learn any exotic vocabulary a highly educated native speaker might vaguely remember.   You make it sound like "proficient" is a yes-or-no criterion.

Comment: @user151413: Let me repeat.  I am very happy that some leading French mathematicians write papers in their excellent and erudite French rather than their merely very good English.  It gives me an opportunity to learn excellent French.

Comment: @user151413 At my school, the use of an English-German dictionary was regarded as gross educational malpractice. With good reason.

Comment: @Karl Yes, for *learning* the language, I can see that. But when I am reading a paper these days where I find a word which I don't know, I will just look it up in a dictionary.  After all, I want to quickly read the paper, not necessarily educate myself about exotic english vocabulary.

Comment: @user151413 I don't get how checking a word in English-Chinese dictionary is faster than in English-English one. And you get the proper meaning of the word, not an imperfect one mangled by translation.

Comment: @ciamej Of course it is faster, it is reading one word rather then reading a longer definition of a word in terms of several other words; if it is a special word it requires context, sample sentences, etc.  
But this is not the point, my point is that is makes paper reading harder for non-native speakers: They have to pause and look up the word, if they are not online (on an airplane or whatever else) they cannot look it up, etc.; it is giving non-native speakers a disadvantage, so I cannot see how people are supportive of that.

Comment: (@ciamej Just checked germane, certainly much faster in a english-german dictionary than a pure english dictionary.  And you get the perfect translation of the word, not a description of the word through other words which *don't* convey its meaning as well (otherwise, why would that word have been necessary in the first place?))

Comment: @user151413 If you claim that we're not talking about Simple English, then what are we talking about? You can simplify the language as much as you wish. Simple English is not even the bottom. Some guidelines on using English in manuals for aeronautic industry go further than Simple English and forbid such words as increase or decrease. Then you can go even lower, with Randal Munroe's book Things Explainer, which uses only 100 most frequent words. Then you get names like up-goer five for Atlas V rocket.

Comment: The simpler you make the language the more accommodating it is for non-native speakers with poor language skills. But it becomes gross. So where is the line? How low should we go? On the other hand, maybe we should not simplify the language at all? Isn't it more natural?

Comment: @ciamej At least in physics, there is a reasonably clear cut between vocabulary regularly used in publications, and vocabulary almost never used in publications.  There is a grey zone, but I don't think it is about this, the question seems to be more about the "basically never used in papers" words.  I'd count "germane" as one of those, for instance.  So we're not talking about not using "increase" here.  And I don't think it is about "natural".  It is about how you deal with people from other countries who don't speak english as their first language.  Do you want to make it easy for them ...

Comment: ... to participate in science, or do you see it as part of your duty to educate them in their command of english.

Comment: @user151413 I don't think such a clear cut really exists in every field. It's very subjective to call out certain words that you personally haven't came across before. Some words are used more often, while some are used rarely. Still, they might be used rarely just because they concern something that is not relevant to each paper, not necessarily because they are so sophisticated.

Comment: But never mind, you missed my point: why is the vocabulary used in physics limited? Because many authors have limited command of the language. That's fine. But in the future, papers of authors with even more limited vocabulary will be published, and then the cut will move towards Simple English, and even lower. Avoiding less used words ultimately leads to erosion of the standard and there's no stopping this.

Comment: @user151413 Additionally, language skills are not necessary only for reading and writing of scientific papers, but also for direct communication between researchers. People travel to conferences, give lectures, attend thesis defences (as a reviewer), go on short term scientific missions, and so on. Having only basic language skills is IMHO not acceptable. Everybody as a professional should strive to improve their language skills in the language in which they are working.

Answer (score 9):

I will preface this with confirming that I am a native speaker of English.

I would say the first two cases given by your co-authors should be corrected though (as many others have pointed out) in the third example the correction is wrong (though I also think it could be written better, and shouldn't have had with).

My feeling is that what you want to do is generate emotion in the reader as they read your paper. You want to build anticipation, tease the solutions and results, and feel the excitement when everything comes together. You want this so that the reader doesn't have to slog through yet another string of logical arguments. One way to achieve this (and I'm guessing this is relevant to at least some cases) is to use less common words from the English language. These may be words that as well as their broad meaning have sublet undertones of meaning flavouring them.

An example of these undertones is my use of flavouring in the previous sentence. Broadly it says there is general information in a sentence, and hints to help understand the meaning of other sentances. Subtlety it suggesting that a writer can take a boring/bland sentence and choose to add further hints of something that makes the text and enjoyment to read.

Another example would be *verdant grass*, broadly it means "green grass" but carries subtle meanings of lots of life. If we needed to use this in some academic text then maybe we might prefer to avoid verdant if possible. We could then use *green grass*, but then we've lost the subtle undertones, but perhaps we could fix that by using lush to get *lush green grass* instead. Now we have something very similar to what we wanted to say but by making use of more common words rather than something that would work brilliantly in a novel.

In addition to my broad thoughts above I'll go through my thoughts on the three sentences and how they could be improved.

**The examples**

For the first example I needed to look up germane, since your primary goal is to communicate information clearly that suggests there would be a better word (e.g. relevant). Only your secondary goal is to make it enjoyable to read, so if making it enjoyable to read requires people to pull out a dictionary or obscure information then it should take a back seat to writing boring but clear text. And don't forget that you should only expect your target audience to be competent at English, not have native level fluency.

> these related works are germane to our present discussion.

Why germane? What does this give that related doesn't, is there any difference from what is said by "these works are related to our present discussion". If there is a difference can you correct this simplified sentence using more common words rather then reaching for a less common one.

One reason I could see you might be wanting to do this is to slow the reader down so that they think more about what you just said, and to separate what follows from what you've just written. In which case you could try something else while still restricting yourself to simple words (e.g. use the passive voice), "The work(s) presented in [citation(s)] must be considered for our present discussion" (though I still feel like this sentence could be improved).

> ...therefore, the scenario considered in [reference] is situated diametrically opposite to ours.

Unlike the first example I (personally) don't have to go to the dictionary for this, though it still feels bad to me. The big picture of what you are saying is
*Scenario in [Ref] is not the same as our work.*
However there are implications made by your choice of words, something like:
*There is a location in parameter space related to our work, and the work in [ref] is located at the complete opposite location.*
The parameter space idea probably comes to me because you used "situated" rather than because of "diametrically".

Why not something like "Therefore, the results in [references] are inconsistent with the scenario we've considered." Does this convey the same ideas that you wanted originally, if not could you start from this and generate what you want to say?

> The experiments in [references] corroborates with our results

Here corroborates is correct but you shouldn't have with. However I feel like what you are conveying in the subtle undertones is wrong. Broadly you are saying *experiments in [refs] agree with our results and thus strengthen our arguement*. However at the subtle layer I feel you are saying *[refs] decided to check our results and will strengthen our claims* which is causally the opposite of what is going on. Depending on what you are trying to say perhaps "Our results corroborate the hypothesis put forward in [ref]". Or if you are trying to use the references to strengthen a claim put forward in your paper, "The experiments in [ref] fit the framework of [put claim here]"

The last thing to remember is that different people will interpret the subtle information differently, though their interpretation is still valid. So when you write like this you can't just assume that everyone will interpret it the same as you do.

But this also means there is flexibility in how you write and so you can develop a style you are comfortable with, enjoy writing, and take pride in the results. However whatever style you develop it must be constrained by the ways that your target audience will interpret it, and the general skill level that the majority of your audience has.

Comment: Something that I think is getting dropped from the discussion here (and in other comments/posts), is that "germane" is not just "related" -- it also calls out that the other work has bearing on the specific aspects of the topic that are under discussion, whereas "related" is a vaguer term and does not as strongly imply relevance.

Comment: @RLH The reason is that I first came across that word in this question, so a quick google didn't give me enough understanding of its use to distinguish between the subtle meanings of related and germane (and perhaps this is happening in other comments/posts/answers as well). That was part of the reason I phrased it as a question, I'll update my answer later based on this info. 

Though to confirm its meaning, how is it different to "strongly related" and can it mean, "relevant in a way that  perfectly answers all the questions you would naturally have".

Comment: Here's an example: Take a paper about automated driving of tractor-trailer trucks, and in particular control strategies for avoiding an unexpected obstacle in the road. A previous paper about having automated cars avoid the obstacle would be related, but the results may not necessarily be germane to the present problem if, e.g., the approach taken in the car paper requires maneuvers that are fundamentally not available to a truck towing a heavy trailer.

Comment: @RLH Yes, "germane" says more than just "related". But you still don't need both words, since "related" doesn't really add anything.

Comment: @RHL germane should be replaced with relevant, not related.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime "Related" has nothing to do with "germane". And in the OP's sentence, "related" would most likely not mean "related to the current discussion" in any case, but "related to each other".

Comment: @Davor I never recommended replacing germane with related. I’m pointing out that germane is distinct from related, and that it would be natural to use both words in the course of reviewing the literature on a topic.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. That makes sense, thank you. I hadn't spotted that interpretation.

Answer (score 8):

Aside from what everybody else has said, I think it's worth noting that you're not prominent in your field (yet). Prominent people have more leeway than newbies. This is unfair, but it's the way it is.

So yes: write as simply as you can, without losing the complexity of the points you're making.

Comment: Great point. By the way: This phenomenon is also visible in Stack Exchange votes. Plus 1 from me.

Comment: You mean prominent people write more comprehensible papers even when they use the same incomprehensible words?

Comment: Skeptical. This would seem to imply that either (a) people who use "flowery" language become top in field (thus desirable!), or (b) people who become prominent change their writing style over time to become more difficult.

Comment: Why do you have to mix this in? Do you personally know the poster and his achievements? Maybe what you write in the 1st paragraph is true, but what is the connection to the topic of discussion.

Comment: @Daniel R. Collins: option (c) : professor BigWig used to go through many corrections in their draft to make the language as clear as possible, but now that they are prominent they can just write stylistic garbage without fear of pushback. Co-authors don't insist, reviewers are intimidated ("if prof BigWig writes thusly, it must be the correct way" + "they know the editor and they evaluate my next grant, I should not call out the style"). This hypothesis is supported by the amount of _scientific_ garbage some BigWigs got away with (if you do not know an example in your field, lucky you!).